# Getting new tweet count Only using Twitterizer

Tags: web-services, twitter, twitterizer

let me first say a big thanks for Twitterizer, it's made my dev work much easier. I'll definitely be donating. In my app, I load tweets using a webservice and since I keep a track of the last tweet, I'd like to be able to just get the count of new tweets.

is there a faster way other than using TwitterTimeline.HomeTimeline()? Since I assume this method fetches all the content?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up counting new tweets clientside and hiding the content. I realised that since I was loading the content there was no need to re-fetch it again later on so I hide all of them in a div until the user expands it.